# Null value being returned from a Stored Procedure using Linq to SQL

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000, null

If I run a stored procedure in my database (SQL 2000) and return the SCOPE_IDENTITY, I receive a value. However, using LINQ to SQL, I get a null value for the Column1 property. Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Can you show us the code that you are using?

Comment: Don't need to. It's been successfully answered below. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have only one SELECT statement at the end of your SP. So, something like this:

```
IF something
DO something
   SET variables
ELSE
   SET variables

SELECT variables
```

Also, rename your column in the select statement and possibly cast it into proper data type. Something like this:

```
SELECT CAST(@variable AS DataType) AS [ColumnName];
```

I ran into this a week ago because I had 2 SELECT statements in a SP and they were screwing each other up. The SP always did what it was supposed to but it always sent null back. Since I switched to what I wrote above it's worked like a charm.

Hope this helps you

Comment: There are other select statements, but further up the chain. they aren't at the end. there's only one at the end. If I run it in SQL Management Studio, only one result is returned and not multiple results. I will try the column thing. Thanks!

Comment: It did work. Specifying the exact cast to the type is what seemed to do it. Thanks!!! I'll have to blog about this.